# Does the following call to call_user_func_array() work?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, php-5.4

I have a couple of libraries that use code similar to the following one.

```
$args = array_merge(array(&$target, $context), $args);
$result = call_user_func_array($callback, $args);
```

The code is different in both the cases, but the code I shown is what essentially is done. The  `$callback` function uses the following signature:

```
function callback(&$target, $context);
```

Both the libraries document that, and third-party code (call it plug-in, or extension) adopts that function signature, which means none of the extensions defines the callback as, e.g.,  `function my_extension_loader_callback($target, $context)`.

What confuses me are the following sentence in the documentation for [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

> Before PHP 5.4, referenced variables in param_arr are passed to the function by reference, regardless of whether the function expects the respective parameter to be passed by reference. This form of call-time pass by reference does not emit a deprecation notice, but it is nonetheless deprecated, and has been removed in PHP 5.4. **Furthermore, this does not apply to internal functions, for which the function signature is honored.** Passing by value when the function expects a parameter by reference results in a warning and having `call_user_func()` return `FALSE`.

In particular, the highlighted sentence seems to suggest that is not done for functions define in PHP code.

Does using `call_user_func_array()` in this way work in PHP 5.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `call_user_func_array`, passing by value when a function expects a reference is considered an error, in newer versions of PHP.

This was valid PHP code before PHP 5.3.3:

```
//first param is pass by reference:
my_function(&$strName){
}

//passing by value, not by reference, is now incorrect if passing by reference is expected:
call_user_func_array("my_function", array($strSomething));

//correct usage
call_user_func_array("my_function", array(&$strSomething));
```

The above pass by value is no longer possible without a warning (my project is also set to throw exceptions on any kind of error (notice, warning, etc).) so I had to fix this.

**Solution**
I've hit this problem and this is how I solved it (I have a small RPC server, so there is no such thing as referenced values after deserializing params):

```
//generic utility function for this kind of situations
function &array_make_references(&$arrSomething)
{ 
    $arrAllValuesReferencesToOriginalValues=array();
    foreach($arrSomething as $mxKey=>&$mxValue)
        $arrAllValuesReferencesToOriginalValues[$mxKey]=&$mxValue;
    return $arrAllValuesReferencesToOriginalValues;
}
```

Although `$strSomething` is not passed by reference, `array_make_references` will make it a reference to itself:

```
call_user_func_array("my_function", array_make_references(array($strSomething)));
```

I think the PHP guys were thinking of helping people catch incorrectly called functions (a well concealed pitfall), which happens often when going through `call_user_func_array`.

Answer (score 1):

If `call_user_func_array()` returns `false` you have a problem, otherwise everything should be fine.

Parameters aren't passed by reference by default anymore, but you do it explicitly.
The only trouble could be that your reference gets lost during `array_merge()`, haven't tested that.

Comment: `call_user_func_array()` returns whatever the called function returns. If the called function also returns `false` as a valid return value, then relying on this returned value for error detection is not good practice.

Answer (score -1):

I've found this same problem when upgrading to PHP5.4 when there were several sites using `call_user_func_array` with arguments passed by reference.

The workaround I've made is very simple and consists on replacing the `call_user_func_array` itself with the full function call using eval(). It's not the most elegant solution but it fits the purpose for me :)

Here's the old code:

```
call_user_func_array($target, &$arguments);
```

Which I replace with:

```
$my_arguments = '';
for ($i=0; $i<count($arguments); $i++) {
    if ($i > 0) { $my_arguments.= ", "; }
    $my_arguments.= "\$arguments[$i]";
}
$evalthis = " $target ( $my_arguments );";
eval($evalthis);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't down-vote the question, but `eval()` is devil. It should not be used.